# Xamarin.Forms accessing controls written in markup from Code

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.forms

Im trying to add some items to a  Listview which i added using Xamarin.Forms markup  in an xaml file.
The button can be accessed by hooking with the click event.But since the listview is empty i need the event like `ondraw` like in winforms, so that i can hook to it when it is drawn.

[image]

In the XAML file I have :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ButtonXaml.ButtonXamlPage">
             <StackLayout>
  <Button Text="Tap for click count!"
    BorderWidth="10"
    TextColor="Red"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
          <ListView 
          HorizontalOptions="Center"

          />

   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In the .cs file i have

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ButtonXaml
{
    public partial class ButtonXamlPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public ButtonXamlPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            ((Button)sender).Text = "You clicked me";
        }
    }
}
```

So should i hook to events in Listview or can i do something like `Resource.getElementbyID` like we do in android

Comment: Why are you trying to hook into when it's *drawn*? Normally you'd populate the view when the form is *loaded* or something similar. Is there any reason you're not using a binding to a view-model here? That would be the more conventional approach - embrace MVVM :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Reason? I dont know how to do it :) Can you provide me with a link to an example or something,im fairly new to xamarin.forms.In android we create a customadaptor and assign it to the listview which i get from the resource using  Resource.getElementbyID,in xamarin.forms how to do this?

Comment: Rather than trying to write Xamarin.Forms code as if it's Android code, I would *strongly* encourage you to read up on the way that Xamarin.Forms works and its idioms. You'll end up with *much* nicer code that way. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_bindings_to_mvvm/ introduces MVVM in Xamarin.Forms, and there's plenty of other documentation available. (I believe you can just provide a `Name` attribute in the XAML and you'll get a variable in the code-behind, but using MVVM would be much cleaner and more testable.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Im in the process of learning xamarin.froms,i will go through it and i will try to use MVVM if its possible for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To access a Forms control in the code-behind, you need to assign it a name, using the `x:Name` attribute

in XAML:

```
<ListView HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="MyList" />
```

in code:

```
MyList.ItemsSource = myData;
```

Comment: Thanks.It works, but the auto complete does not recognize it.

Comment: Pls suggest if i want to access if from class in platform Specific project inherited from PageRenderer using ExportRenderer.

Answer (score 13):

There is a bug in Xamarin where VS doesn't see the defined x:Name
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25409/problem-with-xaml-x-name-and-access-from-code-behind

Say you've defined an image in XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="myImageXName" />
```

Then this should work in code behind:

```
this.FindByName<Image>("myImageXName");
```

Comment: Can confirm. I run into this issue all of the time on Xamarin Studio and need to do this as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was lack of line `XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` in .xaml.cs file.

Example:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }
    ...
}
```