# cs wont detect elements in the xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin.forms

So basically, i'm deciding to write an app for the first time, i chose to make a portable app using Xamarin.Forms and well, here's my cs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Sheet">

    <Grid Height="0" Width="0">

        <GroupBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="0" Margin="-269,-341,0,0" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Xp Gain"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="46" Width="142" >
                <Label Name="lblXpValue" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="259" Margin="68,24,-90,-46" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >0</Label>
                <CheckBox Name="cbTrainer" Height="17" Width="107" TabIndex="261" Margin="-4,4,-103,-21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Checked="cbTrainer_CheckedChanged" >Trainer Pokemon</CheckBox>
                <Label Name="label7" Height="22" Width="65" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="258" Margin="6,24,-71,-46" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Xp Value:</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <Label Name="lblStab" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="257" Margin="0,-101,-205,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >0</Label>
        <Label Name="label42" Height="22" Width="50" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="256" Margin="0,-101,-193,79" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >STAB:</Label>
        <GroupBox Margin="0,-178,-267,95" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="83" Width="109" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Types"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="60" Width="97" >
                <ComboBox Name="cbTypeTwo" Height="21" Width="97" TabIndex="14" Margin="-1,30,-96,-51" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                    <ComboBoxItem>Normal</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Fire</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Water</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Electric</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Grass</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Ice</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Fighting</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Poison</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Ground</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Flying</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Psychic</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Bug</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Rock</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Ghost</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Dragon</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Dark</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Steel</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>None</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <ComboBox Name="cbTypeOne" Height="21" Width="97" TabIndex="13" Margin="-1,4,-96,-25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                    <ComboBoxItem>Normal</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Fire</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Water</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Electric</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Grass</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Ice</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Fighting</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Poison</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Ground</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Flying</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Psychic</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Bug</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Rock</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Ghost</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Dragon</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Dark</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Steel</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>None</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Margin="0,-272,-267,176" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="96" Width="109" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Health"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="73" Width="97" >
                <TextBox Name="tbMaxHealth" Height="20" Width="50" TabIndex="2" Margin="46,30,-96,-50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <Label Name="label36" Height="22" Width="39" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="1" Margin="20,33,-59,-55" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Max:</Label>
                <Label Name="label35" Height="22" Width="53" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="6,7,-59,-29" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Current:</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <Menu Name="msHeader" Height="24" Width="560" TabIndex="21" Margin="-279,-356,-281,332" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            <MenuItem Header="_Options" Name="optionsToolStripMenuItem" >
                <MenuItem Header="_Reset" Name="resetToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="" Name="toolStripSeparator1" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" Name="saveToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Load" Name="loadToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Export" Name="exportToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Set E-Mail" Name="setEMailToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Tools" Name="toolsToolStripMenuItem" >
                <MenuItem Header="Stats..." Name="statsToolStripMenuItem" >
                    <MenuItem Header="Randomize" Name="randomizeToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Reset" Name="resetToolStripMenuItem1" ></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="R_andomize Nature" Name="randomizeNatureToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="" Name="toolStripSeparator3" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="N_otes" Name="notesToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Held Item" Name="heldItemToolStripMenuItem" ></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <GroupBox Margin="0,-71,-267,-26" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="97" Width="243" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Abilities"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="74" Width="231" >
                <ListView Name="lvAbilities" Height="70" Width="240" Margin="-7,1,-233,-71" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                    <ListView.View >
                        <GridView >
                        </GridView >
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Margin="-91,0,-267,-348" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="324" Width="358" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Moves"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="301" Width="346" >
                <TextBox Name="tbEffect" Height="145" Width="155" TabIndex="257" Margin="182,108,-337,-253" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <Label Name="label41" Height="22" Width="47" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="256" Margin="148,111,-195,-133" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Effect:</Label>
                <TextBox Name="tbSpecial" Height="20" Width="155" TabIndex="257" Margin="182,82,-337,-102" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <Label Name="label39" Height="22" Width="54" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="256" Margin="141,85,-195,-107" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Special:</Label>
                <ListView Name="lvMoves" Height="294" Width="126" Margin="-4,1,-122,-295" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                    <ListView.View >
                        <GridView >
                        </GridView >
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Label Name="label40" Height="22" Width="86" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="9" Margin="138,282,-224,-304" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Contest Effect:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblContestEffect" Height="22" Width="9" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="8" Margin="226,191,-235,-213" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ></Label>
                <Label Name="lblContestAppeal" Height="22" Width="9" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="8" Margin="226,173,-235,-195" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ></Label>
                <Label Name="lblContestType" Height="22" Width="9" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="8" Margin="226,155,-235,-177" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ></Label>
                <Label Name="label38" Height="22" Width="91" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="7" Margin="138,269,-229,-291" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Contest Appeal:</Label>
                <Label Name="label37" Height="22" Width="82" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="7" Margin="138,256,-220,-278" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Contest Type:</Label>
                <Label Name="label34" Height="22" Width="51" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="5" Margin="242,33,-293,-55" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Range:</Label>
                <Label Name="label33" Height="22" Width="33" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="5" Margin="260,7,-293,-29" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >AC:</Label>
                <Label Name="label32" Height="22" Width="40" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="4" Margin="142,59,-182,-81" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Freq:</Label>
                <Label Name="label31" Height="22" Width="37" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="3" Margin="145,33,-182,-55" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Roll:</Label>
                <TextBox Name="tbFrequency" Height="20" Width="56" TabIndex="255" Margin="169,56,-225,-76" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbDmgRoll" Height="20" Width="56" TabIndex="255" Margin="169,30,-225,-50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbRange" Height="20" Width="57" TabIndex="255" Margin="280,30,-337,-50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbAccuracyChk" Height="20" Width="57" TabIndex="255" Margin="280,4,-337,-24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbMoveType" Height="20" Width="57" TabIndex="255" Margin="168,4,-225,-24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <Label Name="label30" Height="22" Width="43" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="1" Margin="139,7,-182,-29" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Type:</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Margin="-254,0,97,-348" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="257" Width="157" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Capabilities"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="234" Width="145" >
                <ListView Name="lvCapabilities" Height="230" Width="154" Margin="-7,1,-147,-231" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                    <ListView.View >
                        <GridView >
                        </GridView >
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Margin="0,-178,-149,69" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="109" Width="125" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Evasion Bonuses"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="86" Width="113" >
                <Label Name="label29" Height="22" Width="41" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="3" Margin="34,59,-75,-81" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Both:</Label>
                <Label Name="label28" Height="22" Width="54" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="2" Margin="21,33,-75,-55" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Special:</Label>
                <TextBox Name="tbSpeedBonus" Height="20" Width="50" TabIndex="255" Margin="62,56,-112,-76" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbSpecialBonus" Height="20" Width="50" TabIndex="255" Margin="62,30,-112,-50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbPhysicalBonus" Height="20" Width="50" TabIndex="255" Margin="62,4,-112,-24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBox>
                <Label Name="label27" Height="22" Width="58" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="17,7,-75,-29" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Physical:</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Margin="-254,-178,-15,-26" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="204" Width="269" >
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Stats - 0 points remaining"/>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Canvas Height="181" Width="257" >
                <TextBox Name="tbFinalSpeed" Height="20" Width="53" TabIndex="255" Margin="203,148,-256,-168" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >0</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbFinalSpDef" Height="20" Width="53" TabIndex="255" Margin="203,122,-256,-142" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >0</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbFinalSpAtk" Height="20" Width="53" TabIndex="255" Margin="203,96,-256,-116" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >0</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbFinalDef" Height="20" Width="53" TabIndex="255" Margin="203,70,-256,-90" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >0</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbFinalAtk" Height="20" Width="53" TabIndex="255" Margin="203,44,-256,-64" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >0</TextBox>
                <TextBox Name="tbFinalHP" Height="20" Width="53" TabIndex="255" Margin="203,18,-256,-38" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >0</TextBox>
                <Label Name="label26" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="194,151,-216,-173" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >=</Label>
                <Label Name="label20" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="128,151,-150,-173" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >+</Label>
                <Label Name="label25" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="194,125,-216,-147" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >=</Label>
                <Label Name="label19" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="128,125,-150,-147" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >+</Label>
                <Label Name="label24" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="194,99,-216,-121" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >=</Label>
                <Label Name="label18" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="128,99,-150,-121" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >+</Label>
                <Label Name="label23" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="194,73,-216,-95" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >=</Label>
                <Label Name="label17" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="128,73,-150,-95" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >+</Label>
                <Label Name="label22" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="194,47,-216,-69" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >=</Label>
                <Label Name="label16" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="128,47,-150,-69" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >+</Label>
                <Label Name="label21" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="194,23,-216,-45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >=</Label>
                <Label Name="label15" Height="22" Width="22" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="22" Margin="128,23,-150,-45" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >+</Label>
                <Label Name="label14" Height="22" Width="47" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="21" Margin="148,1,-195,-23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Added</Label>
                <Label Name="label13" Height="22" Width="40" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="20" Margin="86,1,-126,-23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Base</Label>
                <Label Name="lblSpeed" Height="22" Width="50" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="34,151,-84,-173" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Speed:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblSpDef" Height="22" Width="78" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="6,125,-84,-147" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Sp. Defense:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblSpAtk" Height="22" Width="69" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="15,99,-84,-121" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Sp. Attack:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblDef" Height="22" Width="59" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="25,73,-84,-95" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Defense:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblAtk" Height="22" Width="50" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="34,47,-84,-69" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Attack:</Label>
                <Label Name="lblHP" Height="22" Width="34" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="0" Margin="50,21,-84,-43" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >HP:</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </GroupBox>
        <ComboBox Name="cbNature" Height="21" Width="128" TabIndex="6" Margin="0,-206,-130,185" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionChanged="CbNatureSelectedIndexChanged" >
            <ComboBoxItem>Hardy</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Docile</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Proud</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Quirky</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Lazy</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Desperate</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Lonely</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Adamant</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Naughty</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Brave</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Stark</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Bold</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Impish</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Lax</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Relaxed</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Bashful</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Modest</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Mild</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Rash</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Quiet</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Sickly</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Calm</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Gentle</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Careful</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Sassy</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Serious</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Timid</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Hasty</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Jolly</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Na?ve</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Composed</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Dull</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Patient</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Poised</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Stoic</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Name="label6" Height="22" Width="51" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="15" Margin="-36,-203,-15,181" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Nature:</Label>
        <Label Name="label5" Height="22" Width="54" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="14" Margin="-39,-230,-15,208" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Gender:</Label>
        <ComboBox Name="cbGender" Height="21" Width="128" TabIndex="5" Margin="0,-233,-130,212" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            <ComboBoxItem>Male</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Female</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Name="cbSpecies" Height="21" Width="128" TabIndex="3" Margin="0,-273,-130,252" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionChanged="CbSpeciesSelectedIndexChanged" />
        <Label Name="label4" Height="22" Width="57" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="11" Margin="-42,-270,-15,248" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Species:</Label>
        <Label Name="label3" Height="22" Width="72" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="8" Margin="0,-297,-149,275" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Experience:</Label>
        <Label Name="label2" Height="22" Width="45" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="6" Margin="-30,-297,-15,275" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Level:</Label>
        <TextBox Name="tbNickname" Height="20" Width="246" TabIndex="0" TextChanged="TbNicknameTextChanged" Margin="0,-325,-248,305" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Label Name="label1" Height="22" Width="115" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="4" Margin="-100,-322,-15,300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >Pok?mon Nickname:</Label>
        <CheckBox Name="cboxExp" Height="17" Width="72" TabIndex="255" Margin="-107,-298,35,281" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Checked="CboxExpCheckedChanged" >Auto EXP</CheckBox>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I already have made this as a windows application in WinForms so I converted the designer.cs into XAML then put it into a WPF and edited it so it looked right, then stuck the XAML from inside the `<Window></Window>` tags and put them inside the `<ContentPage></ContentPage>` part of the XAML page in my app, however, the cs behind the XAML file can't detect the elements, I can see them in my WPF application and edit them but I can't in my app solution, does anyone know whats going wrong here? did I do something stupid?

Thanks

**EDIT:** So I decided to go start myself again and create the XAML from scratch, I have as follows:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Sheet">
    <Grid>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="imgTest" Source="App1.Sheet"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
     </ContentPage>
```

However, when I type imgTest in the cs behind it says

> imgTest does not exist in this context

Seriously, whats up with this?

Comment: There is no ContentPage type in WPF...

Comment: @mm8 **then stuck the xaml from inside the <Window></Window> tags and put them inside the <ContentPage></ContentPage> part of the xaml page in my app**

Comment: Why are you copying the contents from a WPF app into a Xamarin app? This is doomed to fail since Xamarin.Forms uses a different XAML stack than WPF.

Comment: Riiiiiiight, okay, i didnt know that, thanks! :)

Comment: You should ask a new question if you have another issue and not change your previous question.

Comment: @mm8 it's the same issue, my initial issue was that the xaml controls weren't accessible in my cs file, the issue is still there, it is not fixed

Comment: What's the content of the Sheet.xaml.cs file?

Comment: `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Sheet : ContentPage
    {
        public Sheet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imgPokemon.Source = "";
        }
    }`        if you can read that..

Comment: Does this work?: var img = this.FindByName("imgTest") as Image; You may also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353593/xamarin-forms-accessing-controls-written-in-markup-from-code

Comment: No, it throws this error on the "FindByName" part `The type arguments for method 'NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<T>(Element, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. App1`

Comment: Specify the type arguments explicitly then: FindByName<Image>("imgTest");

Comment: DId you try this or what happened? Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved.

Comment: I'm trying to get a chance to test it, the code is clean as in it isn't picking up any syntax errors but i don't see why it would pick up the elements by using that and wouldn't be able to detect them in the cs file

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it doesn't make much sense to just copy all the XAML markup of a WPF `Window` into a Xamarin.Forms `ContentPage`. This is doomed to fail since Xamarin.Forms uses a different XAML stack than WPF.

Comment: Actually, I once heard that this is one of the main reasons they choose to do just that. Preventing people from copy/pasting their layout and end up with non-mobile friendly screens.